# itemize (the first column) and second column of tabular are not in the same line

Tags: tables, lists, tabularx, itemize

I'm writing my CV and now while compiling my `.tex` file I faced this two problems:

First of all this is my code:

```
    \documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \newenvironment{titlemize}[1]{%
      \paragraph{#1}
      \begin{itemize}}
      {\end{itemize}}

    \begin{document}
    %\Huge \textbf{} %\textbf{bold}
    \section*{\Huge \textbf{Xxxx Xxxxx}}
    \normalsize
    \section{\textbf{Personal Information}}
    Birth: September 25$^{st}$, 1995, xxxxx\\
    Citizenship: xxxx 

    \section{\textbf{Education}}
        %\begin{tabular}{p{0.85\textwidth}  p{0.15\textwidth} }
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X X}
        %$\bullet$ & \textbf{High School,Allameh Helli(Exceptional Talents HighSchool(NODET)),Tehran,Iran} & 2007-2011
            %\begin{itemize}
            %\textbf{High School,Allameh Helli(Exceptional Talents HighSchool(NODET)),Tehran,Iran} 
        %   \end{itemize} & \textbf{2007 - 2011} \\
    \begin{itemize}

    \item \textbf{High School Allameh Helli(Exeptional Talents High School(NODET)),xxxx}
    \end{itemize}&
    {2007 - 2011}

    \end{tabularx}


    \end{document}
```

1. I want my CV uses bullet dot so I used itemize and I created table with two columns for (information| date) representation, now my problem is that information and date are not horizontally in the same row
2. my second problem is when I put a space in my information text (in `.tex`), pdf shows more spaces!

Output file:

[image: Output file]

I would appreciate for your solutions, link, ...

Answer (score 1):

Here you are: the trick is to make LaTeX believe the itemize environment happens at the beginning of a minipage, so that no vertical spacing is added.

I took the opportunity to improve the layout of your list with the `enumitem` package, and corrected some typos.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newenvironment{titlemize}[1]{%
  \paragraph{#1}
  \begin{itemize}}
  {\end{itemize}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section*{\Huge \textbf{Xxxx Xxxxx}}
\normalsize
\section{\textbf{Personal Information}}
Birth: September 25\textsuperscript{th}, 1995, xxxxx\\
Citizenship: xxxx

\section{\textbf{Education}}

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\compress}X X@{}}
\begin{itemize}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*]
\item \textbf{High School Allameh Helli(Exceptional Talents High School (NODET)), xxxx}
\end{itemize}&
{2007 - 2011}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Added:*

If you want to have `X` columns of unequal sizes, you have to play with `>{\hsize=xxx\hsize}X`, the condition being that the sum of the `xxx` coefficients be equal to the number of X columns.  In the following code, I managed to have the first column width thrice the second column width, with the coefficients `1.5--0.5`.

However, if you have a list environment in the cell, it uses for its line width the width of a standard `X` column; so we have to teach it the true width of the X column. For this, we can use the key `before={\linewidth=\hsize`}:

```
 \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\hsize=1.5\hsize\compress}X |>{\hsize=0.5\hsize\arraybackslash}X@{}}
\begin{itemize}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, before={\linewidth=\hsize} ]
\item High School Allameh Helli (Exceptional Talents High School (NODET)), xxxx
\end{itemize}&
{2007 - 2011}
\end{tabularx}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer
i have another question : if we want change the width of the columns how can it possible? because we fill the preamble prameter with this command :  "\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\compress}X X@{}}" and i have sreached and the structure of diffrent width  is like  "\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{b s s}" how can we satisfy both of this conditions together ?

Comment: You can change the ratio of the two `X` columns. Which ratio would you like to have?

Comment: You would have one big column and two small ones?

Comment: one big column for text and little for date

Comment: @Captain: If you specify for the second column `l` or, say,  `p{3cm}`, there's no problem. There's a problem when you want to have two `X` columns with coefficients that make their widths unequal, but I finally fixed it as explained in my add-on to the initial answer. Please  see if it's OK for you.

Answer (score 0):

you have (at least) two possibilities so solve your problem:

- tweak `itemize` environment, for example with help of package `enumitem`, in which you remove standard vertical space before environment
- not use itemize at all and place bullets in separate column

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}    
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newenvironment{titlemize}[1]{%
  \paragraph{#1}
  \begin{itemize}}
  {\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}
\section*{\Huge \textbf{Xxxx Xxxxx}}
\normalsize
\section{\textbf{Personal Information}}
Birth: September 25$^{st}$, 1995, xxxxx\\
Citizenship: xxxx

\section{Education (1)}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X X}
\begin{itemize}[topsep = 0.5ex,
%                leftmargin=*,   
                before = \vspace{-\baselineskip}]    
\item \textbf{High School Allameh Helli (Exeptional Talents High School(NODET)), xxxx}
\end{itemize}   &
{2007 - 2011}
\end{tabularx}

\section{Education (2)}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\textbullet}c L L}
    &   \textbf{High School Allameh Helli 
                (Exeptional Talents High School(NODET)), xxxx}
    &   {2007 - 2011}                   \\  \addlinespace
    &   \textbf{High School Allameh Helli
                (Exeptional Talents High School(NODET)), xxxx}
    &   {2007 - 2011}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]